# Azure Bot Service not working in Web Chat behind proxy

Tags: azure, websocket, proxy, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a basic C# bot in Azure and have been doing some tests with it. I am able to debug locally and test that the bot works and responds normally, However, Web Chat does not seem to work (either the "test in web chat" within Azure or the embed code provided under "Channels" menu. The bot does not respond and the following can be seen in the browser's console:

[image: websocket error]

```
botchat.js:20 WebSocket connection to 'wss://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/b00803da186843c08e057a03f1af26d3/stream?watermark=5&t=PdrKaTBDGps.dAA.YgAwADAAOAAwADMAZABhADEAOAA2ADgANAAzAGMAMAA4AGUAMAA1ADcAYQAwADMAZgAxAGEAZgAyADYAZAAzAA.PWqO6rz50wE.O0xFG-RkTZ0.306EPN7-0X_MGGfBUujpWoKN8Xm942hqpn_BVxbRe_M' 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
(anonymous) @ botchat.js:20
```

This happens with any chat bot created in Azure even without any code changes but only when in my company environment, which is behind a proxy. I am almost certain that this is somehow the cause of the problem, but I have no clue why nor how I might approach the proxy team to report the problem nor what I may need to ask them to unblock.

**The Question:** Am I right to assume that this is a proxy problem or should I investigate something else and, if this is indeed a proxy issue, what do I need to do/ask to unblock to solve it?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If your company has a 'proxy team', it is likely someone on that team will probably know what is configured that is blocking wss: ... have you asked them?

Comment: I would suggest you to try that with open network (Mobile wifi or something) if it is working this way then it is for sure proxy problem.
And if you are behind a corporate proxy i think there is no other way to other than contacting the respective department.

Comment: The downside is that this proxy team is not very 'technical'. I had a hard time trying to make them understand what was being blocked, but after 2 days they finally did it and it started to function as expected!

Comment: @YuriW sorry, just to clarify: was this an issue with your Azure server (that is, regardless of where you were using Web Chat from, you were encountering this issue, until the URL was whitelisted on the server), or an issue with the network you were using (aka if you tried using Web Chat from a home network, it would work fine, and it was only while at work that Web Chat wasn't receiving the response, and the team just whitelisted the URL on the network)? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I ask because I'm experiencing the same issue; however, it seems to be with the company's Azure subscription specifically. I'm on the company's network - when I deploy my bot code to my personal Azure account, the web chat works successfully, but when I deploy it to the company Azure account, I'm experiencing the same issue you are (sends successfully but no response). Wondering if it's the same problem, or a different problem with the same symptom...

Comment: When you say "same issue", check in your browser debugger to ensure the error messages are the same as the ones I've indicated else it could be something entirely different. For me, whenever accessing from my work computer (which is behind a proxy whether from home or not) then I had this problem. The subscription I use does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a Proxy issue, You can talk to your admin team and get these links removed from their firewall settings so you can get access. We do get this issue's in our company we do the same as i have suggested.\

Happy coding!!!

Comment: You're right, it was a proxy issue. It was just hard to have them understand exactly what needed to be unlocked as they are not technical. But it worked, finally! Hopefully this helps if someone else runs into a problem like this. I just had to add webchat.botframework.com to the whitelist.